# 19.10 wont load after 1st update

Tags: updates, 19.10, reboot

I want to learn more about Linux and virtualization with KVM, so I have a HP Zbook laptop with a SSD drive that’s been loaded w/ 19.10.  The install works but after running the first update, the system will not load after a reboot.  I can’t even start another terminal using the ctrl-alt F* keys.  Is this a problem with an update, or possibly something that’s not configured correctly in BIOS?  Thanks for your time and help

Comment: I did notice that there was a problem with the live CD before I installed.  There was a error with automatically logging in to the desktop.  Perhaps a corrupt install disk?

Comment: I rolled back to 19.04, and had no problems installing or updating. I did see when booting the 19.04 live dvd, it did not have a problem in unmounting the dvd like the 19.10 live did when it booted.